# str_split and str_trim and simplify in R

Tags: r, stringr, strsplit

This is for people using stringr in R.

I want to split a name into first and trim any stray spaces.

```
> str_trim(str_split(c("John Smith"),"\\s+"))
[1] "c(\"John\", \"Smith\")"
```

Where are all the escaped "s coming from?

I was expecting c("John","Smith")

Comment: while i can't answer the question, I'm quite certain it has something to do with the fact that `str_split` ( without simplify) returns a list and str_trim handles lists in this ...weird way, for the lack of a better word. The underlying methods from  `stringi`  package also do the same.

Comment: If you `str_split` on `"\\s+"` like you do, you'll never actually get any "stray spaces". They all get gobbled up as separators. See `str_split(" John Smythe Smith ","\\s+")` for example. So the `str_trim` is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this, you are using `str_trim` in a wrong way on a list output of `str_split`:

```
library("stringr")
str_trim(str_split("John Smith","\\s")[[1]])
```

**Output**:

```
> str_trim(str_split("John Smith","\\s")[[1]])
[1] "John"  "Smith"
```

Comment: Many thanks. Having looked at the answers, I understand how to use the functions better ... and probably need to put the trim inside the split. 

    res <- str_split(str_trim(c("   first    last    "), "\\s+")[[1]]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `unlist` to produce a vector of strings.

```
library("stringr")
unlist(str_split(c("John Smith"),"\\s+"))
```